# Can't draw with Buffer Object

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

So, I'm trying to study vbo and just do some examples, but opengl is killing me. I've been four hours trying to do this code work, but I dont have a clue why this dont work. 
I was trying to draw 4 squares with different colors.
But if I try to draw using `GL_POINTS` i only see 4 points in the screen, and is supposed to be 9 points. If I try using `GL_QUADS` it simply don't draw nothing.
The interesting is that when I change this line:

```
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 16, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

to this:

```
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 64, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

Opengl draw the 9 dots, but only that, GL_QUADS dont work.
Please, someone give me a light on this problem, it's killing me!!
The complete code is here:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(offset) ((GLfloat*) NULL + offset)

#define VERTICES 0
#define INDICES 1
#define NUM_BUFFERS 2

void init_2(){

GLuint buffers[NUM_BUFFERS];

GLfloat vertices[][3]= { 
                {0.0, 0.0,  0.0},
                {0.0, 40.0, 0.0},
                {0.0, 80.0, 0.0},
                {40.0, 0.0, 0.0},
                {40.0, 40.0, 0.0},
                {40.0, 80.0, 0.0},
                {80.0, 0.0, 0.0},
                {80.0, 40.0, 0.0},
                {80.0, 80.0, 0.0}
              };

GLuint indices[][4] = {
              {0, 1, 4, 3}, 
              {1, 2, 5, 4}, 
              {3, 4, 7, 6}, 
              {4, 5, 8, 7}
            };    

glGenBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, buffers);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[VERTICES]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[INDICES]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void display(void){  

glPushMatrix();         
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 16, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
}

void init() 
{
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  gluOrtho2D((GLdouble) -1.0, (GLdouble) 90.0, (GLdouble) -1.0, (GLdouble) 90.0);  
  init2();
}

int main(int argv, char** argc) {

  glutInit(&argv, argc);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
  glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100,100); 
  glutCreateWindow("myCode.cpp");
  init();
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
GLuint indices[][4] = {
...
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 16, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

You declare `GLuint` indices, but then tell `glDrawElements` that you're giving it bytes.

`GLuint` is a 32-bit type, so there are 4 bytes for each. As your index data is very small, each 32-bit value has only data in the bottom byte, leaving the rest as zero.

So in the first 16 bytes, which are the first 4 `GLuint`s, there are only 4 discrete values, so you see 4 points. If you try 64 (which is 16 * 4), you will see all 9 points. However these points are mixed in with a lot of zeros, so when you try to render as `GL_QUADS`, nothing will be drawn.